# MEMS microphone different output voltage at the same dB

Tags: microphone

I am trying to measure noise using the [ADMP401 (MEMS) sensor.](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/ADMP401.pdf)

In the dynamic sound (applause, the sound of hitting the desk, etc.,) a sensor output of + -200mV is obtained. However, for the sound of a cell phone at the same dB, it gets about + -50mV.

[image]

[image]

The upper waveform is the sound of a mobile phone, and the lower waveform is the sound of a mobile phone similar to the dB of the dynamic sound.

I used a high pass filter, weighting filter, preamp, etc. to solve this, but it still has a lot of change in dynamic sound. And if the sensor recognizes the dynamic sound, clipping occurs in the negative direction. Both sounds are around 100dB.

[image]

The circuit diagram is as follows. The XPG1 part was used instead of the ADMP401 sensor.

I experimented with preamp and weighting filter circuit in front of C1, but the problem mentioned above is not caught. I've spent a lot of time trying to solve it, but it didn't work.

Can you help me solve it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is part of the sensor datasheet. Even if I interpret it, I am not sure where the problem is. Do I need to change the sensor or use a different filter? How to get a constant output in dB regardless of the type of sound?

[image]

As the dynamic sound mentioned above has a large change in dB in the low frequency band, a weighting filter is used to catch the low frequency.

Comment: How are you measuring the "dB" of the sound?

Comment: @JRE 

I used a sound level meter. DB was measured by applying sound between the sensor microphone and the sound level meter.

Answer (score 1):

You fix it by implementing the weighting used in sound pressure level meters.

Sound pressure level (SPL) meters filter the sound before measuring it.  They are not normally used with the straight microphone input.

Most SPL meters follow the [A weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_level_meter#Frequency_weighting) curve.  There are other standards as well.

They look like this:

[image]

<sub>From the Wikipedia article</sub>

That removes a lot of frequencies that will be in your "dynamic sound."

Due to different frequency content, it is entirely possible for two sounds to measure the same loudness on an SPL meter but still have drastic differences in appearance (and voltage levels) when viewed on an oscilloscope.

Another thing that contributes to this is that SPL meters also filter the SPL measurement itself.  A short but loud noise won't read as high as a continuous but less loud noise.  You'll need a low pass filter one the output of your peak detector to mimic the time response curves for the different time weightings used.

Wikipedia has a chart of the time weightings:

[image: Time weighting]

Your circuit appears to have something like the A-weighting implemented but not the time weighting.

---

One last thing:

Different microphones have different dynamic ranges.  A sound that your SPL meter can accurately measure may cause your MEMS microphone to distort and deliver incorrect levels.

Microphones also have different frequency responses.  Your MEMS microphone loses signal below about 100 Hz and above about 10 kHz.  That will distort your A-weighting curve.

---

Missed the most important part.

[dB is a logarithmic scale.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel)

If you double the voltage, that looks like an enormous difference in your oscilloscope view.  It is only 3dB, though.

You'll need to implement a [log amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_amplifier) in your circuit and scale the result to get correct dB readings.

It might be easier to use an ADC to sample the peak detector output and do the dB conversions in a microprocessor than to implement an accurate log amplifier.

Comment: thank you for the reply.

 If you look at the datasheet, it seems that the C weighting filter is basically included. So I connected the A weighting filter with an analog circuit.
 There is still a difference in output voltage between the dynamic sound at the same dB measured on the sound level meter and the sound of the phone.
 
 Is there any other way around this? I want to get the same output voltage if the same dB depending on the dB measured by the sound level meter regardless of the type of sound.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
 It should be implemented only in analog without ADC. Let's test it by implementing lowpassfilter and log amplifier.